# Why doesn't the java.lang.Object class clone() method have a body?

Tags: java, clone

There are lot's of questions on this platform regarding clone() method of Object class. Everyone is answering different. There are lots of question regarding why clone() is protected. Some says..

> 1. clone() is protected, so we have to provide our own clone() and indirectly call Object.clone() from it.
> 2. clone() is protected soo outside to java.lang package we can access this method in subclass directly or with subclass Object only.
> 3. clone must not be called on non-cloneable objects, therefore it is not made public.

Now Here are my questions.

1. If the above 2nd point is correct then how we can **access clone() in subclass directly**.
2. What are **non cloneable objects**.
3. What is the need to be Override clone() in subclass in case of cloning. Whereas the protected member of another package we can access inside another package by inheriting its parent class directly.
4. Why Object.clone() dosen't have body part.

   protected native Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 protected native Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;
```

**This is the prototype of clone method in Object class**

**why no Body ?**

It is a native method so it doesn’t have the body cause it’s body is provided by native library which is written in c language same as Jvm 
Or we can say we just need to give instruction to the jvm that we need to clone and the rest is taken care by Jvm

**Why protected why not public?**

Now clone() method is given as protected not public so that we couldn't clone Object class  object

This behaviour provided to the sub classes or the classes created by the users .And we know that protected members are accessible outside the package inside 
Subclass only and on subclass object only.

**why override?**

We override it in subclass because there is a possibility that we need to call clone method outside the class and because of protected Behaviour we won’t be able to do that, so we override it with public modifier …prototype mentioned below

```
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;
```

**why object need to be cloneable?**

Since the cloning object is done by Jvm so there jvm need a information  like on which object cloning is required and for that object is required to have cloneable signature ,
And for that we need to implement cloneable interface which is a marker interface and it will inform to jvm that  this specific object need cloning

Comment: Suppose if method of Object.clone() is public not protected. Then we can also create clone for Object class object then what trouble we'hve to face.

Comment: Since Object class is a base class there is no requirements of cloning it. It doesn't have any specific state to itself. It just provide 11 different behavior which are to be required by sub class and we know clone is used to keep a copy of object state. So we can say that's why sun ms kept clone as protected in object class

Comment: Java methods don't have prototypes.  They have declarations (and signatures).  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.  You are mixing up Java terminology with the terminology of other languages.

Comment: you should search dictionary for prototype

Answer (score 3):

> If the above 2nd point is correct then how we can access clone() in subclass directly.

It is correct.

Like this:

```
public class Foo implements Cloneable {  
    public Foo copy() {
        return super.clone();  // or just `clone()`
    }
}
```

The point is that a method of a class can call `protected` methods in its superclass.  Note that `Foo` needs to `implement Cloneable` if you want to *enable* the default implementation of `clone()` in `java.lang.Object`.  But you don't have to enable it, and you don't have to use it even if it is enabled; see below.

> What are non cloneable objects.

They are objects that you can't call `clone()` on (successfully).  The exact meaning depends on the context:

- It could be that objects that don't have a `public` clone method, and you cannot call the `protected` one.
- It could be that the (non-public) clone method does not work; e.g. because the class doesn't `implement Cloneable` or extend one that does.

> What is the need to override `clone()` in subclass in case of cloning. Whereas the protected member of another package we can access inside another package by inheriting its parent class directly.

There are three distinct reasons for overriding `clone()`:

1. To make `clone()` accessible to other classes that wouldn't be able to access it otherwise.  That is, any classes that are NOT in the same package and do NOT extend this class.
2. To alter the behavior of the `clone()` method:

   - You don't have to call `super.clone()`.  You can implement the cloning behavior anyway that you like.
   - You could do things to the clone after calling `super.clone()`.
3. To override the return type so that you don't need to cast the result of `clone()`.  (The return type of `Object::clone` is `Object`.)

> Why Object.clone() doesn't have body part.

Did you notice the `native` modifier? Native methods do not have a body.

The cloning behavior of `java.lang.Object` is implemented in native code.  It is doing things that cannot be done in ordinary Java code.  (Or using Java reflection, for that matter.)

Comment: Suppose if method of Object.clone() is public not protected. Then we can also create clone for Object class object then what trouble we'hve to face.

Comment: Abstraction violation.  If `Object::clone` was public then a class would have no control over what can clone it.